# Using str.replace in a for loop

Tags: python

I am working on an assignment that is asking me to change the below code so that line 4 uses str.isalnum and lines 5-7 become uses only one line using str.replace.

```
s = 'p55w-r@d'
result = ''
for c in s:
    if(c not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'):
        result += '*'
    else:
        result += c
print(result)
```

This is what I have so far:

```
s = 'p55w-r@d'
result = ''
for c in s:
    if(c.isalnum() == False):
        result += c.replace(c,'*')
print(result)
```

The output for the second code needs to equal the output of code 1:

```
p55w*r*d
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the else part and you are done :

```
s = 'p55w-r@d'
result = ''
for c in s:
    if(c.isalnum() == False):
        result += c.replace(c,'*')
    else:
        result +=c 
print(result)

p55w*r*d
```

Answer (score 0):

I have idea how to make same in 2 strings:

```
s = 'p55w-r@d'
print(''.join(map(lambda x: x if x.isalnum() else '*', s)))
```

OUT:

```
p55w*r*d
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to meet your assignment's requirements while still making sense would be:

```
s = 'p55w-r@d'
result = s  # Note the change here
for c in set(s):  # set(..) is not strictly necessary, but avoids repeated chars
    if not c.isalnum():
        result = result.replace(c, '*')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use if else after equal.

```
s = 'p55w-r@d'
result = ''
for c in s:
    result +=  '*' if(c.isalnum() == False) else c 
print(result)
>>>p55w*r*d # output
```