# Using str.replace to replace non-alphanumeric characters with asterisks in a for loop

Tags: python, string, replace

I am trying to rewrite lines 5-8 with only 2 lines using the str.replace method

```
s = 'pa55w-r@'
result = ''
for c in s:
    if(c not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'):
    result += '*'
else:
    result += c
print(result)
```

Below is what I've got so far.

```
s = 'pa55w-r@'
result = ''
for c in s:
    if(c not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'):
        result = s.replace(c,"*")
print(result)
```

However, I am not sure why the output is

```
pa55w-r*
```

instead of

```
pa55w*r*
```

which the original code has? I have tried comparing with one other example at [Using str.replace in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647440/using-str-replace-in-a-for-loop) however, the suggestions are to add an else statement which I have actually removed to condense the code from 3 lines to 2. Any input would be appreciated

Ahh, I almost forgot to mention, I cannot use the regex method which seems to be the common answer that I've seen so far during my search for tips throughout stackoverflow.

Comment: [Your first method is working fine](https://rextester.com/ZYG49943), and I can't reproduce your error.  Note that `re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]', '*', s)` is a much more terse and clean approach IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the input Tim. Currently just finished learning about classes and flow control and our professor through in some string methods to spice some things up. Definitely will look into regex when I get a deeper understanding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the *result* variable is only seeing one replacement pass.  The fix is to make successive assignments to *s* so that it get closer and closer to the intended result:

```
s = 'pa55w-r@'
for c in s:
    if(c not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'):
        s = s.replace(c,"*")
print(s)
```

This outputs:

```
pa55w*r*
```

Comment: Hi Raymond, I did notice that! When I included in my code     ```result += s.replace(c,'*')``` I received an output of     ```p55w*r@p@55wr*```  each where the asterisk should have been! Is this what you mean by only "one" replacement pass? I did actually come up with an option where I printed s actually similar to your code. I just wanted to check that  there was absolutely no other way to rewrite the OG code with lines 5-8 replaced with just 2 lines printing for result (also without using regex). Once again, thanks for all the help!